# Событие и анимация в зависимости от количества дочерних элементов. WPF

Tags: c#, xaml, анимация

Никак не получается решить задачу в стиле `MVVM`. Есть что-то вроде выпадающего списка элементов

```
<TextBlock x:Name="CurItem" Text="Тут выбранный элемент">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
            <media:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource Анимация-показываем_список_элементов_ItemsList}"/>
        </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBlock>
<ListBox x:Name="ItemsList" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSourceList}"/>
```

Я хочу чтоб событие `Tapped` не срабатывало бы, если в `ListBox` только 1 элемент.

Comment: А написать в обработчике события проверку на количество элементов - нельзя? Или вам надо чтобы это решала VM?

Comment: Мне кажется неправильным выносить эту штуку в code-behind. Конечно так проще, но мы ведь стремимся к лучшим практикам, верно? =)

Comment: Отключение тапа для одного элемента в списке - вполне себе плановое по моему поведение, я бы оставил в ивенте.

Comment: Неиспользование code-behind это не «лучшая практика», это слепое следование мантре. Ничего плохого в том, что *чисто* GUI логика находится в code-behind.

Comment: @Monk: Так у меня и нету ивента в code-behind, тут обращение к анимации через вьюху. Пока что временно создал событие в code behind, чтоб разработка не стояла. Если не найду ответ, то так и оставлю.

Comment: @ixSci: А почему слепое? Паттерн же такой есть. Понимаю что он не идеален далеко, но лучше ведь чтоб все придерживались неидеального паттерна, чем каждый делал по-разному.

Comment: Паттерн в GUI разработки всего один — логика приложения(т.к. называемая бизнес-логика), должна быть отделена от представления. Но это не значит, что если код разметки не позволяет нормально описывать события, то не нужно выносить *логику представления* в code-behind — он за этим и нужен, затем, что XAML уж очень лимитирован. Это никаким образом не нарушает паттерна.

Comment: @ixSci: Понял, спасибо за развернутый ответ